# unable to connect unity and mysql using a php webservice

Tags: php, mysql, database, unity-game-engine

I'm using scripts from the page Server Side Highscores Tutorial for my purposes. I edited it slightly but it doesn't work. The value is not saving and I keep getting this message in php page:

> Notice: Undefined index: Name in C:\xampp\htdocs\unitypb\saveVerant.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Value in C:\xampp\htdocs\unitypb\saveVerant.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: hash in  C:\xampp\htdocs\unitypb\saveVerant.php on line 8

This is the php code

```
<?php 
        $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
        mysql_select_db('unitypb') or die('Could not select database');

        // Strings must be escaped to prevent SQL injection attack. 
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'], $db); 
        $score = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['score'], $db); 
        $hash = $_GET['hash']; 

        $secretKey="mySecretKey"; # Change this value to match the value stored in the client javascript below 

        $real_hash = md5($name . $score . $secretKey); 
        if($real_hash == $hash) { 
            // Send variables for the MySQL database class. 
            $query = "INSERT INTO verant VALUES (NULL,  '$name', '$score');"; 
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
        } 
?>
```

and this is the c# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SQL_InputVS : MonoBehaviour {

    private string secretKey = "mySecretKey"; // Edit this value and make sure it's the same as the one stored on the server
    public string addScoreURL = "http://localhost/unitypb/saveVerant.php?"; //be sure to add a ? to your url


    Text text;

    void Awake (){
        text = transform.Find ("Text").GetComponent <Text> ();
    }


    public void sendDatabase () {
        StartCoroutine (saveValue ("Verant-" + this.transform.name, text.text));
    }


    IEnumerator saveValue (string name, string score) {

        //This connects to a server side php script that will add the name and score to a MySQL DB.
        // Supply it with a string representing the players name and the players score.
        string hash = Md5Sum (name + score + secretKey);

        string post_url = addScoreURL + "name=" + WWW.EscapeURL(name) + "&score=" + score+ "&hash=" + hash;

        // Post the URL to the site and create a download object to get the result.
        WWW hs_post = new WWW(post_url);
        yield return hs_post; // Wait until the download is done

        if (hs_post.error != null)
        {
            print("There was an error: " + hs_post.error);
        }

    }

    public string Md5Sum(string strToEncrypt)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding ue = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = ue.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);

        // encrypt bytes
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);

        // Convert the encrypted bytes back to a string (base 16)
        string hashString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            hashString += System.Convert.ToString(hashBytes[i], 16).PadLeft(2, '0');
        }

        return hashString.PadLeft(32, '0');
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: purely for the record, Spin.  for high scores you'd very simply use GameCenter or GooglePlayServices.  it's totally free.  it would be very unrealistic to do it yourself by hand these days

Comment: PHP interpreter is telling you that you dont have in GET name, score and hash indexes. Maybe try to use POST?

Comment: I believe there's a problem with URL. Can you please give us value of 'post_url' variable. write Debug.Log(post_url.ToString()); and share with us to check more.

Comment: @tadman thanks for your suggestion, later on i might learn more about them, but now since I'm new to this, it should be easier to just follow and modify the tutorial

Comment: @JoeBlow we want to use it in our own server and it is actually not for highscore but something works similar

Comment: @JerrySwitalski I actually tried it with _POST but didn't work either

Comment: @Naeim the command returns this lines:

http://localhost/unitypb/saveVerant.php?name=Verant-7&score=he&hash=f53ece393177df447e2ad3538190d5d4
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<saveValue>c__Iterator5:MoveNext() (at Assets/Script/SQL_InputVS.cs:42)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
SQL_InputVS:sendDatabase() (at Assets/Script/SQL_InputVS.cs:23)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

Comment: if I change line 6-8 into this, the error message gone but they return empty value:

 $name = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_GET['name'], $db)); 
 $score = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_GET['score'], $db)); 
 $hash = isset($_GET['hash']);

Comment: ok now the problem is from your PHP side.  at first change php code like this to check if your're connecting to database or not .<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?> 
open  http://localhost/unitypb/saveVerant.php?name=Verant-7&score=he&hash=f53ece393177df447e2ad3538190d5d4    in browser and see what's happening there.paste the result here.

Comment: @Naeim and all, thanks for your input. I have made it, the script runs very well now. It seemed the c# script was the problem. I searched and found modified script by Appymole here and it works fine for my app.
http://www.appymole.com/tutorial/

Comment: You should compose your solution into a answer, so that other people that run into it also can be helped.

Comment: @Spiningit, please add an answer to this question so that it doesn't remain open in the pending list, I just wasted a few minutes of my life seeing how to help you, only realize you'd already fixed it. I'm sure others will do the same....

Answer (score -1):

Quote from Spiningit's comment.

> I have made it, the script runs very well now. It seemed the c# script
>   was the problem. I searched and found modified script by Appymole here
>   and it works fine for my app. appymole.com/tutorial